# Partitioned ORC table shows up empty in Hive

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, partitioning, orc

I've written a Spark dataframe to partitioned `ORC` files like this:

```
df.repartition("LOADED")\
  .write\
  .partitionBy("LOADED")\
  .format("orc")\
  .save("location")
```

Everything is on the disk correctly.
After that, I wanted to create a Hive table from it, like:

```
CREATE TABLE table USING ORC LOCATION 'location'
```

The command runs without any errors. But if I try to query the table, it's empty.

I've tried to do the same without partitioning, and it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?
The partitioned folders look like: `LOADED=2019-11-16`

*For reference: I want to write the data to Azure Blob Storage, and create a Hive table from it in a different cluster.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to update the partition info on the table so Hive can list the partitions presents. This is done through the MSCK REPAIR command:

```
spark.sql("MSCK REPAIR TABLE <tableName>")
```

More info on this command [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-repair-table.html)

**Quick example here**

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from table").show
20/03/28 17:12:46 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
+------+------+
|column|LOADED|
+------+------+
+------+------+

scala> spark.sql("MSCK REPAIR TABLE table")


scala> spark.sql("select * from table").show
+------+----------+
|column|    LOADED|
+------+----------+
|     a|2019-11-16|
|     c|2019-11-16|
|     b|2019-11-17|
+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You are writing data directly to the **`location`** not through hiveQL statements in this case we need to update the metadata of the hive table from hive/spark using:

```
msck repair table <db_name>.<table_name>;
```

(or)

```
alter table <db_name>.<table_name> add partition(`LOADED`='<value>') location '<location_of the specific partition>';
```

Then run the below command to list out partitions from the table:

```
show partitions <db_name>.<table_name>;
```